# Grafana select query throwing error - "Found no column named time or time_sec"

Tags: mysql, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I am using Grafana mysql data connector and trying to write a select query.
The select query is throwing an error - `"Found no column named time or time_sec"`

```
Here is the query
SELECT main_id, ipaddress FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 5):

This happens when you are using a "Graph" visualisation, with X-Axis mode set to "Time" like this, because grafana is trying to find what time series to map the graph against:

[image: graph-visualisation-with-time-mode]

From your query, it seems like you're looking to visualise a data that does not have a time series.

**Depending on the data you are playing with & your goal**, either:

- Change the X-Axis mode to "Series" and pick the relevant numeric column to map the X-Axis against
- Or choose a more apt Visualization other than "Graph"
- Or change the query to have a "time" column

Comment: I have modified my query and included `complete_dt` column as below:
`SELECT main_id, ipaddress, complete_dt, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(complete_dt) as time_sec
FROM table1 p where p.complete_dt >= '2017-10-01';`

I am now getting below error:
`Value column must have numeric datatype, column: complete_dt type: time.Time value: 2019-01-02 07:42:52 +0000 UTC`